# Toggle each component separetly on multiple components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-bootstrap

I have list of the same component rendered on screen where each component has a button when clicked it toggles between `false` and `true` to `show` and `hide` that specific component

How to achieve that?

```
  <ListGroupItem active tag="button" action onClick={this.props.toggleCollapse}>

      <Collapse isOpen={this.props.collapse} />
```

Comment: Can Please share the structure of the List. What will the properties in the List item

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to achieve that

here https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactstrap-v5-4rezrr?file=ListGroupCollapse.js